# Connection between tables in mySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have a `users` table in my database , where i have an **deviceID** , a **pushToken** an **OS** .

I have another table `subscriptions`. This table has the **deviceID** and the **pushToken** of subscribed users.

When i make a new INSERT to the `subscriptions` table i only have the **deviceID** of the user that wants to subscribe. Is there a way that these 2 tables could connect , so that when i insert the **deviceID** , the **pushToken** would be automatically inserted from the other table ? Or if not automatically , maybe there would be an easy way to refer to it since the tables would be connected? I am asking so that i would avoid another query to the `users` table to get the **pushToken** , and then INSERT it to the `subscriptions` table

I think it has something to do with foreign keys , but i am not sure. Can someone provide me a simple coding example , or a tutorial on the matter?

I am using php.

Answer (score 0):

This is very bad design. The last name column of the subscriptions table is redundant. Unless there is a compelling reason for keeping it, I would be inclined to drop it.

Comment: i completed changed the names of the tables so that anyone could understand my example... actually there are devideIDs and pushTokens..

Comment: the `last name` is probably the effective relationship reference.  so you wouldn't drop `last name` without replacing it a `user_id` column to keep a relationship to `user` table

Comment: guys look my edit. i am sorry for the confusion but this is not the case. the names are made up so that the question is not too technical..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your database looks like this:

```
users
-----
deviceID
pushToken
OS

subscriptions
-------------
deviceID
pushToken
```

If this is the case, you could insert the deviceID and the pushToken into the subscriptions table at the same time even if you only have the deviceID using a query like this (assuming "123ABC" is the deviceID you are inserting):

```
INSERT subscriptions (deviceID, pushToken)
SELECT deviceID, pushToken
FROM users
WHERE deviceID = '123ABC';
```

However, this is not usually considered a good design for a database.  Typically, you don't want to repeat data in two places.  In this case, the deviceID and pushToken are stored in both the users table and the subscriptions table.  This might be an improvement:

```
users
-----
id
deviceID
pushToken
OS

subscriptions
-------------
id
user_id
```

If your database was structured this way, you could insert a new record into the subscriptions table using this SQL (again for a deviceID of "123ABC"):

```
INSERT subscriptions (user_id)
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE deviceID = '123ABC';
```

I didn't specifically insert the id because I am assuming it would be an automatically incrementing id provided by the database.

It is not necessary to put the deviceID in the subscriptions table.  Just having the user id is enough to "connect" the tables.  You would "connect" these tables using SQL from your php code.  If you want to know the deviceID and pushToken of the user with subscription 25, the SQL might look like this:

```
SELECT deviceID, pushToken FROM users, subscriptions 
WHERE users.id = subscriptions.user_id AND subscriptions.id = 25;
```

If you want to know all the subscriptions owned by a user with deviceID "123ABC", try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users, subscriptions
WHERE users.id = subscriptions.user_id AND user.deviceID = '123ABC';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i completed changed the names of the tables so that anyone could understand my example... actually there are devideIDs and pushTokens..

Comment: It might be better to describe your actual tables so we can more easily help.  However, if your fields are about the subscription, it is fine to have them in the subscriptions table, but if they are about the user, they definitely don't belong in the subscriptions table.  The user_id is the only thing needed in the subscriptions table to get everything else you need from the users table when you want to know something about the user who owns that subscription.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information about your database.  I edited my answer in response.